# Многопоточность на живом примере, как реализовать?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Изучаю многопоточность и для примера делаю программку, которая собирает данные из локально сети.

Сперва я собираю, список пингующихся хостов в сети.

```
public async static Task<List<string>> PingSuccess()
{
    int i = 1;
    List<string> ips = new List<string>();
    List<string> ips_complite = new List<string>();
    while (i <= 255)
    {
        ips.Add(ip_base + i);
        i++;
    }
    var pingTargetHosts = ips;

    var pingTasks = pingTargetHosts.Select(host => new Ping().SendPingAsync(host, 2000)).ToList();
    var pingResults = await Task.WhenAll(pingTasks);
    foreach (var ping in pingResults)
    {
        if (ping.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            ips_complite.Add(ping.Address.ToString());
        }
    }

    return ips_complite;
}
```

Затем мне нужно понять, под какой операционной системой работают все эти хосты.

Я должен взять `List` из метода выше и с помощью `foreach` перебрать его до конца. В обычном режиме, это происходит очень долго, потому-что я обращаюсь по WMI, последовательно к каждому компу и жду от него ответа.

```
 public static object OSVersion(object ip)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + (string)ip + "\\root\\cimv2");
                scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                foreach (ManagementObject os in searcher.Get())
                {
                    result = os["Caption"].ToString();
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Как правильно перебрать мне это лист и с помощью чего, чтобы я создал к примеру 10 потоков, которые отправят запрос и при появлении ответа, сразу же будут выводить на консоль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

Например так:

```
List<string> ips = await PingSuccess();
ParallelOptions opts = new ParallelOptions();
opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10;

Parallel.ForEach<string>(ips, opts, x =>
{
    var osVer = OSVersion(x);
    Console.WriteLine($"IP: {x} => OS: {osVer}");
});
```

Comment: Ставить `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` от балды не нужно. Лучше попробовать несколько значений: ..., X/2, X (значение по умолчанию), X*2, ..., где Х -- количество процессоров.

Comment: @andreycha. По хорошему надо `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` должно ровняться количеству потоков процессора, т.к. "лишние" потоки будут простаивать, ожидая своей очереди. Но каких-либо серьёзных проблем  при сравнительно малых значений `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` возникнуть не должно